# How to convert Clustered Index scan to Clustered Index seek

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a delete statement that runs through multiple async threads wherein sometimes one thread deadlocks with other. Essentially delete statement uses Clustered Index scan to select the records to be deleted causing page level deadlocks. 
Changing clustered index scan to  index seek will get rid of deadlocks. 
Note: I am running this on SQL Server 2012

When I tried to simulate problem on development environment, I could get query to use clustered index seek or scan based on the data in other table used for comparison.

Here are my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    Col1 [int] NOT NULL,
    Col2 [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Col1 ASC,
    Col2 ASC
))

Create table #Table2(Col1 INT)
```

Delete statement deletes data from Table1 after comparing it with #Table2.
When #Table2 has sequenced data, query goes for Clustered Index Seek.
On the other hand, #Table2 has scattered data (That's what is the state in Prod),  query goes for Clustered Index Seek.

```
/* Scenario 1 : that leads to Clustered Index Scan on Table1 */
INSERT INTO #Table2(Col1)
SELECT TOP 5000 Col1 from Table2 ORDER BY NEWID()

DELETE IA FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN #Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
-------------------------------------------------------

/* Scenario 2:  that leads to Clustered Index Seek on Table1*/
INSERT INTO #Table2(Col1)
SELECT TOP 5000 Col1 from Table2 ORDER BY Col1

DELETE IA FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN #Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Here I am not sure why data in #Table2 should decide if Scan or seek operation used on Table1.
And how do I achieve to change Scan to Seek in Scenario#1.

Comment: There's a scan on the first queries because you're ordering by `NEWID()`'; therefore the full table has to be scanned because a value for `NEWID()` needs to be generated for every row. You can't get a seek for that.

Comment: I believe in your test scenario you're not considering one thing when evaluating the queries that generate SEEK or SCAN. Primarily, I'm talking about table and column level statistics. When you're creating `Table2` with `ORDER BY Col1` you're essentially creating a clone of a ordered sub-set of data from `Table1`. This will help when doing the `DELETE` because your rows are already sorted by the clustering key `(COOL! - less work to search than scan)`. In the other scenario, where you're sorting by `NEWID()` you're essentially loosing this sort that forces the optimizer to go into a `SCAN`.

Comment: Why would SQL Server interpret `ORDER BY NEWID()` and `ORDER BY 1, 3, 12` @RaduGheorghiu?

Comment: @Larnu Ok, nevermind. Learned something today. I'll cleanup my comments.

Comment: @Larnu, I am using NEWID() to get random data in #Table2. But that somehow affecting operation on Table1 in Delete query

Answer (score 0):

There might be several factors considered by optimizer when choosing scan or seek operation (hardware difference, current available resources etc.)
Try to create non-clustered index on Col1 on Table1 and either clustered or non-clustered index on Col1 on Table2

Comment: I tried it. For delete statement, it changes from clustered index scan to non-clustered index scan on Table1.